# VB.net how to make stream reader ignore some line?

Tags: vb.net, string, httpwebrequest, streamreader

i am using a stream reader to get the HTML of some page, but there are lines that i want to ignore, such as if a line starts with `<span>`

any advice?
Here is my function

```
Public Function GetPageHTMLReaderNoPrx(ByVal address As Uri) As StreamReader
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest
  Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
  Dim reader As StreamReader

  Try
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Select Case CType(response, Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
      Case 200
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default)

      Case Else
        MsgBox(CType(response, Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
    End Select
  Catch
    If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
  End Try
  Return reader
End Function
```

this is how the HTML looks like

```
<tr>Text
<span>show all</span>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it right? Generally with HTML, you are not supposed to be looking at lines, and rather consider HTML tags.

Comment: @Neolisk the line starts like this <span>&nbsp , and i want to ignore it

Comment: @and it ends with</span> with no other tags in the same line, did it using a string and it worked fine, except i want to use a reader

Comment: I understand, but you should be instead looking at tags and use those as a base, *not lines*. Because if you load your HTML (or its relevant parts) into an XDocument, you can easily ignore anything by using LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: @Neolisk my problem is the <span> tag is inside a <tr> tag that i select with HTML Agility pack to get its content, the line above the <span> contains text that i want to keep

Comment: @user1570048: see both of my solutions below - one is using `String`s and another one using `XElement`, and decide which is better for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using strings, you could do something like this:

```vb
Do
  Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
  If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do 'end of stream
  If line.StarsWith("<span>") Then Exit Do 'ignore this line
  'otherwise do some processing here
  '...
Loop
```

But this approach is not stable - any minor change in the input HTML can break your flow.

More elegant solution would be using `XElement`:

```
Dim xml = <tr>Text
            <span>show all</span>
          </tr>
xml.<span>.Remove()
MsgBox(xml.Value.Trim)
```